# What does "modulo $n$" mean in this context?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and
$$f(a,b,c)=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi x i}{n^2}a(b+c-[b+c])\right).$$
Here $x\in\{0,...,n-1\}$ and $[b+c]=b+c\mod n$.

Now, it is given that the following holds
$$f(a,b,c)f(b,c,d)f(a+b,c,d)^{-1}f(a,b+c,d)f(a,b,c+d)^{-1}=1$$

> My question is:
>   What does $b+c\mod n$ mean here?

**Thoughts:**
My assumption was that it is the remainder of division by $n$. However, I calculated
$a(b+c-[b+c])+b(c+d-[c+d])-(a+b)(c+d-[c+d])+a(b+c+d-[b+c+d])-a(b+c+d-[b+c+d])
=a(b-d+[c+d]-[b+c])$.
But we can find examples such that
$$\exp\left(\frac{2\pi x i}{n^2}a(b-d+[c+d]-[b+c])\right)\neq 1$$
if we take $[\cdot]$ to be the remainder. 
So what else could it be?

Edit:
The formula given in the source in the comments is
$$\delta\alpha(g_1,...,g_{k+1})=\alpha(g_1,...,g_k)^{(-1)^{k+1}}\alpha(g_2,...,g_{k+1})\prod_{i=1}^k\alpha(g_1,...,g_ig_{i+1},...,g_{k+1})^{(-1)^{i}}$$
The condition which must be satisfied is
$$\delta\alpha=1$$ 
so in our case this would give
$$f(a,b,c)f(b,c,d)f(a+b,c,d)^{-1}f(a,b+c,d)f(a,b,c+d)^{-1}=1.$$

Comment: Can you mention one such example specifically?

Comment: @skyking According to the answer of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121065/explicit-3-cocycle-of-a-cyclic-group (and other sources I found online), $f$ should satisfy a certain condition, namely the one I state in my question.

Comment: You still haven't told us where "it is given". That equation $f(a,b,c)\ldots=1$ looks suspicious, and we would like to check that you have it right.

Comment: You used the wrong formula in your counter example. It should be $[c+d]$

Comment: @TonyK Sorry, I misunderstood that. The condition can be found on page 12 of http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/qg-winter2005/group.pdf

Comment: @skyking You are right, I will search for another one

Comment: Take $n=3,a=1,b=2,c=1,d=1$ then $(b-d+[c+d]-[b+c])=2-1+2-0=3$, but $3/9$ is not an integer

Comment: "The condition can be found...": No it can't. Do you mean the page containing the heading "3. Topological Actions"? I see no such formula there. If the formula in the question is your re-phrasing of a formula from that paper, then I think you must have made a mistake.

Comment: @TonyK See edit, please

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not going to try and decipher that.. But if you replace $f(a,b,c)$ by $f(a,c,d)$ in your product (or indeed $f(a,d,c)$), then it's easy to see that it's true; otherwise it looks false.

Comment: @TonyK The formula is quite easy, since $k=3$ and we don't have that many terms. According to me, you should then obtain $f(a,b,c)$ and not the ones you mention