# Cocycle condition in group cohomology

Tags: modular-arithmetic, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group and $V$ a multiplicative abelian group. Then the cocycle condition is given by
$$\delta\alpha(g_1,...,g_{k+1})=\alpha(g_1,...,g_k)^{(-1)^{k+1}}\alpha(g_2,...,g_{k+1})\prod_{i=1}^k\alpha(g_1,...,g_ig_{i+1},...,g_{k+1})^{(-1)^{i}}=1.$$

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $V=U(1)$.

> What would the condition be for $k=3$?

I think it is
$$\delta\alpha(a,b,c,d)=\alpha(a,b,c)\alpha(b,c,d)\alpha(a+b,c,d)^{-1}\alpha(a,b+c,d)\alpha(a,b,c+d)^{-1}=1$$
Is this correct?

Comment: It seems correct.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Could you then take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2323594/what-does-modulo-n-mean-in-this-context please? Because I do not see what is going wrong